# Where to find libc.so.0

Tags: linux, mips

I'm running a MIPS image in Qemu and a program I'm trying to run shows that libc.so.0 is not found. Libc.so.6 is found in /lib/mipsel-linux-gnu

Does anyone know where I can find libc.so.0 or solve this issue?

Comment: Is the program the right architecture? Sometimes this error is shown in the case of an architecture conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a link to `libc.so.6` to correct the problem:

```
ln -s /lib/mipsel-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/mipsel-linux-gnu/libc.so.0
```

Comment: This is a kind of dirty solution to the problem. Sonames are different usually because they don't export the same symbols any more - in some cases you'll get away with it, in a lot, it will break your application.